# In warhammer 40k can I combines these armies?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I have an Ezekiel, Grand Master of Librarians, which is a dark angels HQ and I have a grey knight army. Can I use Ezekiel as my HQ?

Comment: And if not what librarian can i use in the army? doesn't have to be a HQ.

Comment: Are you asking if you can combine two units in a single army, or are you asking if you can use one of them as your HQ?

Comment: I have a full 1.5k point grey knight army but no HQ so can i use that dark angels librarian as my HQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always take Ezekiel and say he counts as a Grey Knights librarian. Remember they are your models, and you can paint them how you like. Nobody can object because you used a slightly different model.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: in the 7th edition of WH40k, you can create an *X* point *Unbound* army from any units you have, so yes. (Note that *Unbound* armies have some limitations when it comes to holding objectives, etc., so look it up in the rulebook.)

---

Longer answer: based on your comment to your question and depending on what rules your game group has on army building, you probably want to create a *Battle Forged* army, which you cannot create with the 1500 points of non-HQ *Grey Knights* and a *Dark Angels* HQ.

*Grey Knights* and *Dark Angels* can be taken as allies, but as per the rules for taking allies, you need to take the allies in an *Allied Detachment* and your main force in a *Combined Arms Detachment*.

For a *Combined Arms Detachment* you need, and can have:

- **1-2 HQ**
- **2-6 Troops**
- 0-3 Elites
- 0-3 Fast Attack
- 0-3 Heavy Support
- 0-1 Fortifications
- 0-1 Lord of War

So you need at least one *Grey Knights* HQ for your main detachment. For an *Allied Detachment* you need, and can have:

- **1 HQ**
- **1-2 Troops**
- 0-1 Elites
- 0-1 Fast Attack
- 0-1 Heavy Support

So to wield *Ezekiel* with your *Grey Knights* in an appropriate detachment you would need to take at least one *Dark Angels* Troop with him.

---

If you're just playing with your friends, you can probably agree with them that you would both play with 1500p, and you would just not have a HQ. But for more organised games, you need to get a *Grey Knights* HQ, but you would only need a single model to make your army follow the rules. After all, every army needs a leader!

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't take him inside a GK formation, but you could have him join a GK squad (say, Paladins with a Librarian) since he is an Independent Character.